# Use day (cell with date) in a VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a main sheet with my data and 31 possible sheets with additional data used for input for various calculations. I want to use a VLOOKUP to grab the correct data, but Iml having a hard time with the additional sheet reference. I'm hoping to make this a dynamic formula based on the date in the third column on the main sheet.

This is what currently works:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'1'!$A$1:$B$153, 2,TRUE )
```

I'm hoping to get something like the below to work:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,' "Day(C2)" '!$A$1:$B$153, 2,TRUE )
```

where C2 is my date, so then it would grab the day from that date and do the lookup against that sheet and range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `INDIRECT`.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'" & "1" & "'!$A$1:$B$153"),2,TRUE)
```

Now simply replace `"1"` with `Day(C2)`

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'" & DAY(C2) & "'!$A$1:$B$153"),2,TRUE)
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It's not working, but I think I needed the direction to the indirect.  What is the indirect exactly?

Comment: Strange it is not working for you because it does for me :) Hope the value `DAY(C2)` is as desired?

Comment: See the screenshot that I just uploaded. It works for me :)

Comment: More about Indirect [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Comment: Yup, exactly what I am hoping to do. I'll research more on indrect. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem of indirect if you are using the formula as I have shown you. `1` ensure that there is no leading or trailing space in the sheet name `2` Check you regional settings. Based on your regional settings Day(c2) can either return a "1" or a "7"

Comment: No leading or trailing spaces in the sheet name.

Comment: =Day(C2)  displays the day as 1 as I am expecting.

Comment: Got it...Thanks, typo on my end.